# Allow multiple taxonomy term values on term listing page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to return results of multiple taxonomy terms on the `taxonomy/term/%tid` page?

For example, `taxonomy/term/203+221` or `taxonomy/term/203/221` should display all nodes with either one of those two terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the path `taxonomy/term/203+221` (which will yield the nodes tagged with either 203 OR 221) is possible by making a slight change to the Contextual Filter of the taxonomy/term/%tid view (which you should have enabled in Structure > Views > Taxonomy Term.

Expand the Advanced section of the view configuration, click on the first Contextual filter "Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)".

[image: First contextual filter]

You will see a checkbox that allows multiple values, which is checked by default.

[image: Allow multiple values checkbox]

However, to get this working I had to scroll further down to the "Specify validation criteria" section and change the "Filter value type" to "Terms separated by a , or +".

[image: Filter value type]

Now you should be able to use multiple term IDs in your URL, combined with a "+", to see all nodes tagged with any of the IDs in the list. You can test out various URL arguments using the Views Auto preview:

[image: Previewing results]